# Implementing delay in VHDL state machine

Tags: vhdl, fifo, xilinx

I'm writing a state machine which controls data flow from a chip by setting and reading read/write enables. My clock is running at 27 MHz giving a period of 37 ns. However the specification for the chip I'm communicating with requires I hold my 'read request' signal for at least 50 ns. Of course this isn't possible to do in one cycle since my period is 37 ns.

I have considered I could create an additional state which does nothing but flag the next state to be the one I actually complete the read on, hence adding another period delay (meaning I hold 'read request' for 74 ns), but this doesn't sound like good practice.

The other option is perhaps to use a counter, but I wonder if there's perhaps yet another option I haven't visited yet?

How should one implement delay in a state machine when a state should last longer than one clock period?

Thanks!

[image: T1 must be greater than 50 ns]
(T1 must be greater than 50 ns)
Please [see here](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT245R.pdf&ei=vwCJUJyXPMOQhQeQsYGABg&usg=AFQjCNGaC351imKRH5z8t9mBHTl9egicxQ&sig2=gFj_N9jVJtayzC0qfaTaZg) for the full datasheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delays are only reliably doable using the clock - adding an extra "tick" either via an extra state or using a counter in the existing state is perfectly acceptable to my mind.  The counter has the possibility of being more flexible if you re-use the same state machine with a slower external chip (or if you use a different clock frequency to feed the FPGA) - you can just change the maximum count, instead of adding multiple "wait" states to the state machine.

Comment: That's reassuring, I had been putting in extra wait states and thinking this seemed a bit ridiculous, but I suppose it makes sense if it's just one tick you need. The counter is probably a better idea but even the counters complexity might be necessary to vary with application.